# PySpark join dataframes with LIKE

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I try to join dataframes using a LIKE expression in which the conditions (content of *LIKE*) is stores in a column. Is it possible in PySpark 2.3?

```
Source dataframe:
+---------+----------+
|firstname|middlename|
+---------+----------+
|    James|          |
|  Michael|      Rose|
|   Robert|  Williams|
|    Maria|      Anne|
+---------+----------+
 
Second dataframe
+---------+----+
|condition|dest|
+---------+----+
|      %a%|Box1|
|      %b%|Box2|
+---------+----+

Expected result:
+---------+----------+---------+----+
|firstname|middlename|condition|dest|
+---------+----------+---------+----+
|    James|          |      %a%|Box1|
|  Michael|      Rose|      %a%|Box1|
|   Robert|  Williams|      %b%|Box2|
|    Maria|      Anne|      %a%|Box1|
+---------+----------+---------+----+
```

Let me reproduce the issue on the sample below.
Let's create a sample dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data = [("James",""),
    ("Michael","Rose"),
    ("Robert","Williams"),
    ("Maria","Anne")
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True)
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show()
```

and the second one:

```
mapping = [("%a%","Box1"),("%b%","Box2")]
  
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("condition",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("dest",StringType(),True)
  ])
  
map = spark.createDataFrame(data=mapping,schema=schema)
map.show()
```

If I am rights, it is not possible to use LIKE during join dataframes, so I have created a crossJoin and tried to use a filter with like, but is it possible to take the content from a column, not a fixed string? This is invalid syntax of cource, but I am looking for another solution:

```
df.crossJoin(map).filter(df.firstname.like(map.condition)).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Any expression can be used as a join condition. True, with DataFrame API [like](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.like.html#pyspark.sql.Column.like) function's parameter can only be `str`, not `Column`, so you can't have `col("firstname").like(col("condition"))`. However SQL version does not have this limitation so you can leverage [expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr):

```
df.join(map, expr("firstname like condition")).show()
```

Or just plain SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
map.createOrReplaceTempView("map")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df JOIN map ON firstname like condition").show()
```

Both return the same result:

```
+---------+----------+---------+----+
|firstname|middlename|condition|dest|
+---------+----------+---------+----+
|    James|          |      %a%|Box1|
|  Michael|      Rose|      %a%|Box1|
|   Robert|  Williams|      %b%|Box2|
|    Maria|      Anne|      %a%|Box1|
+---------+----------+---------+----+
```